# Creating a custom SQL checked exception in java?

Tags: java, sql, exception

I know how to create a basic custom checked exception, but I want to be able to create an exception that checks the following:

1. I basically have some tables in a DB, in that DB I have a table **message** with 2 columns message and queue. I can only enter a message with a queue number,if that queue number exists in table **queue_table**(ie foreign key concept). 
   I want to be able to check, that if a person retreives topmost message from a queue (in table message),(ie retreives topmost row with a particular queue number) that there exists that queue number in the queue_table table. If it doesnt I want it to trigger an exception called QueueDoesNotExistException.
   Without the exception, the query to obtain messages from a non existing queue in queue_table gives me **null**, so I am not sure if an existing exception will be useful.

So I have the following :

```
package asl.exceptions;

public class QueueDoesNotExistException extends Exception {
    public QueueDoesNotExistException(){



    }
}
```

I am not sure how to handle this, I dint find any resources for this, or am I looking at the wrong place?

I read this :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlexception.html

But dint find it useful.

Comment: You are trying to perform work in the application layer that should be done in the database.  You want not a "foreign key *concept*" but rather a genuine foreign key constraint.  With a suitable constraint in place and enforced by the database, the application layer would not need to perform a test such as you describe at all.

Comment: As John suggests, a combination of `NOT NULL` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints against the column would be enough to prevent data corruption.

Comment: @john I understand what you are saying, but I do not know how to do it, you see I have a foreign key constraint, but it does not prevent a query. For example if you have a series of rows and I query for the first message in queue 12, but queue 12 does not exist yet, how would a NOT NULL / foreign key constraint solve this?

Comment: I mean that the query looks in message table for a queue 12, since its not there it returns a null.

Comment: Please post all relevant information, i.e. the queries involved and the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to catch DB-specific exception thrown by your JDBC driver first. then you can wrap it in your exception and propagate further.
but exception-driven logic is rarely a good design.

Comment: As I said, it doesnt throw an sql exception, it just gives me null, could you suggest how would I do this using your method?

Comment: select * from table where key = non-existent-key is perfectly valid. it's hard to make it throw an exception. what you need is do a query using a procedure that can throw the exception you need. but, again - this is bad design. i'm only trying to achieve your idea about throwing exception from DB.

Comment: my main aim is to alert user/throw exception for an operation that isnt right in this system,im not sure how to do this

Comment: like @user1766417 mentioned, ideally you shouldn't go to database at all if you found that the queue with this name doesn't exist. thus, the exception you need has to be thrown from your logic, not from JDBC.

Comment: maybe you can maintain a cache of queues in the layer where you query messages or do a query to check if queue_table has this record before going to messages.

Answer (score 0):

You should never let the flow get to the point where a customer is trying to access a message from a non-existent queue. You check for queue existence first thing in the workflow and abort the workflow with an exception, without ever making the second query for messages in the queue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What about if the queue exists when you perform the check but then doesn't when you try to read the message?

Comment: I undestand what you say now! But i dont get how I would do it using foreign key constraint, that wudnt throw an exception when someone queries the message table

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, it seems you are trying to validate *the query itself*, as opposed to ensuring that it cannot return invalid data.  Apparently, you also want to distinguish between a query that returns zero rows on account of the specified queue not being recorded in the DB, and a query that returns zero rows because there are simply no messages available in that queue.  I'm doubtful of the usefulness of these pursuits, but if you insist, then here's an approach you could take:

1. Ensure that your `Connection` is not in auto-commit mode (`connection.setAutoCommit(false)`)
2. Attempt to select the specified queue from the `queue_table` by its ID.  If that fails, then roll back the connection's transaction and throw the exception of your choice.
3. Otherwise, perform the main query as ordinarily you would do, and unless it throws, commit the transaction.
4. Be watchful for the query returning zero rows, and handle the situation however is appropriate.
5. If you rely on changing the autocommit mode as part of the procedure, be sure to record and restore the original autocommit mode, including in the event of an exception.

I apologize if that seems simple or nonmagical, or whatever.